# How to add blur effect in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

How to add blur to a View in React Native, just like we apply it to an Image or BackgroundImage? If the view has translucent background using RGBA, I want to add blur to it also.

Sample Code

```
<ImageBackground style={styles.bg}>
 <View style={styles.content} />
</ImageBackground>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bg: {
   width: "100%",
   height: "100%"
  },
  content:{
    width: "70%",
    height: "70%",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,355,0.4)",
    alignSelf: "center"
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to blur elements over an image. A great idea is to have 2 images, the first will always be in the background and the second will be a child of a position absolute View over the image with overflow hidden. So you just need to make sure this child image has exactly the same size as the one in the background and the opposite position of the absolutely positioned View.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Image, View } from 'react-native';

import yourAsset from 'your/asset/folder/file.jpg';

const ImageBlur = () => {
  const [containerSize, setContainerSize] = useState({
    height: undefined,
    width: undefined,
  });

  return (
    <View
      onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => {
        setContainerSize({
          width: nativeEvent.layout.width,
          height: nativeEvent.layout.height,
        });
      }}
      style={{
        position: 'relative',
        width: '100%',
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      }}
    >
      <Image
        style={{ position: 'absolute', height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
        resizeMode="contain"
        source={yourAsset}
      />

      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: 'black',
          width: 100,
          height: 150,
          left: 100,
          top: 40,
          overflow: 'hidden',
        }}
      >
        <Image
          blurRadius={10}
          source={yourAsset}
          style={{
            width: containerSize.width,
            height: containerSize.height,
            left: -100,
            top: -40,
            opacity: 0.7,
          }}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
        { any children here will be blurred }
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ImageBlur;
```

I also wrote a [Medium post](https://ggraeff.medium.com/a-creative-and-performant-way-of-blur-elements-views-in-react-native-ios-android-42e6aea98654) explaining the concept and created a [react-native-blur-view-image](https://github.com/gustavograeff/react-native-blur-view-image) Github repository for how I came up with this implementation and some usage examples. Also, there is the performance test feedback.

Answer (score -1):

You can use opacity

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
bg: {
 width: “100%”,
 height: “100%”, 
Opacity:0.5
},
content:{
  width: “70%”,
  height: “70%”,
  backgroundColor: “rgba(255,255,355,0.4)”,
  alignSelf: “center”
}


})
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to do something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ImageBackground, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const  BlurImage = () => {
        return (
            <ImageBackground source={require('your picture')} style={styles.ImageBackground}>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}> CSS Tricks </Text>

                    <Text style={styles.text}>You can style your Text and View as you deem fit</Text>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        );
}

export default BlurImage;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ImageBackground: {
        flex: 1,
        width: null,
        height: null,
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.6 )',
    },
    text: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 24
    }
});
```