# How to create blur effect at bottom of flatlist in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to archive blur "gradient" effect at the bottom of flatlist, something like this

[image]

So how can archive this in react-native, i'm thinking about shadow, like "inner shadow"
, but is there right way to archive this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fade the edge of a div with just CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666063/how-to-fade-the-edge-of-a-div-with-just-css)

Comment: Yes, it very similar, i will give it a try in react native

Comment: It has been answered here in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63510083/how-to-add-blur-effect-in-react-native

Comment: as per you question, the bottom whole part will be a component with gradient as background.